# WPF Trigger animation when Visibility is changed?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, triggers, controltemplate

Well i have a custom control and when `Visibility` is changed to `Visible` I have a `Trigger` with a enter/exit action but the problem is that when the exit action fires the `Visibility` is no longer `Visible` so the animation can't be seen how would I fix this?

here is my `Trigger`:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Hide}"/>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Show}"/>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: That's right. Tricky stuff. I'd solve this problem with attached properties + value coercion. Take a look here: [WPF Fade Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013817/wpf-fade-animation/1015635#1015635). Hope this helps. Cheers, Anvaka.

Comment: Does this have a fade animation in it? can i edit this so it only delays the hide/collapse until my animation is done?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing as Petoj.

Comment: @Petoj, @jpierson: Of course you can do whatever you want with the code. It has build-in animation, and I would go with suggested approach in my sample. Because waiting for external animation to complete sounds like unnecessary complexity. Though if you really want to have it, you can make attached property value more sophisticated, and pass animation as one of its values... I feel like it's hard to give complete solution in this comment. If you need more, please post a question, and I'll give more elaborate answer :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this too and failed. I think it is not possible to accomplish this in a simple `ControlTemplate` with a `Trigger` on the `Visibility` property. What you can do is add an `Opacity` animation From 1 To 0 to a `Trigger` for a different property, for instance a `DependencyProperty` that you add in the code behind yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to set `Visibility` for animation period.
In such case there is no need in any codebehind.

Comment: im not 100% sure but wouldent the HideStoryboard trigger the ShowStoryboard if it changed the value of Visibility?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve it. Not 100 % pure, but works for me:

Don't use `Visibility` property, but use `Opacity` and `Tag` property.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" 
                            BorderThickness="2" 
                            BorderBrush="DodgerBlue"
                            Background="#CC4f9dea" >
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            <Button x:Name="btnClose" Opacity="0" Content="X" Style="{StaticResource RoundedButtonStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Tag" TargetName="btnClose" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>

<Style x:Key="RoundedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="15" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Visible">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.0" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.5" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```