# MVVM with animations (should I use VisualStateManager?)

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm, datatemplate, visualstatemanager

I've got a View.xaml with the following set in Resources-section:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MyFirstViewModel}">
    <Views:MyFirstView Content="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MySecondViewModel}">
    <Views:MySecondView Content="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the content of the View.xaml I have:

```
<!-- SelectedMyViewModel is either set to MyFirstViewModel or MySecondViewModel -->
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedMyViewModel}" />
```

When the SelectedMyViewModel changes I'd like to have a animation, so that the current view is faded out and the new view is faded in...

Somehow I feel this should be possible via the VisualStateManager - but I can't figure out how!

This is a WPF 4.0 project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe able to you the answer in this question to assist you [WPF Fade Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013817/wpf-fade-animation/1015635#1015635).

They are doing a FadeIn/FadeOut on visibility. It might be possible to change the Trigger from...

```
<Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
```

to...

```
<Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
```

So my idea would be that in transitioning between ViewModels you would do something like

```
public void SwapViewModels()
{
    // SelectedMyViewModel contains a MyFirstViewModel
    // Setting to null fires the Animation to fadeout
    SelectedMyViewModel = null;

    // Setting the Value to anything but null, should fire the fadein animation
    SelectedMyViewModel = new MySecondViewModel();
}
```

I haven't tested the code but hopefully it gives you a starting point.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of your answer, but I went another route - but I sure your answer is correct - hence the acceptance!

Comment: @kennethkryger: Care to add your route as an answer? =)