# Multiple style triggers not working

Tags: .net, wpf

The following style trigger works fine and fades in my control when I make it visible:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1.4"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

Now I add another trigger to my style for it to fade out when I make it invisible:

```
<Trigger Property="FrameworkElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1.4"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
</Trigger>
```

But this doesn't work and even corrupts the behavior of the first trigger too. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? are you expecting to see the control fade out when you just made it invisible, it wont fade if you cant see it. there are some good workarounds here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013817/wpf-fade-animation

Comment: @sa_ddam213: Thanks for the link. I'm trying Nock's method, but can't really make it work. Where do I add this style, and where does the dependency property go?

Comment: Is this for a particular control, or for all controls?

Comment: A particular one, a wait animation basically.

Comment: Then just add the DependacyProperty to that UserControl, and set the Style TargetType to that UserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments you've got cover this answer well. However if you're still having trouble with the implementation of it, you can use

[This sample download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o00ebe6wjshdy4w/WpfApplication67.rar) which is pretty much the exact implementation as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097133/1834662)

- In the example, `MainWindow` hosts a `UserControl` whose `Visibility` can be toggled via a `Button` from `MainWindow` which in-turn uses the `IsOpen` DP of the UserControl to give the fade in/out effect.

The `Style` mentioned is specified for the `UserControl` and after adding the DP to the UserControl, you pretty much use the `IsOpen` property to toggle Visibility xith Fade In/Out henceforth.

Comment: That's a whole lot of help. I was able to take your work further and make my fade out animation "synchronous" in the sense that setting `IsOpen` to `false` will stop the code from moving to next line till the fade out is complete. Thanks a ton.