# WPF: how to implement a button that make 2 other buttons visible with fading

Tags: wpf, split-button

I want to Implement special button and i don't know even how to start with this.

I want my `Button`'s content property to be: `Play`. When clicking on it, I want 2 other `Buttons` to pop up in the left and in the right sides: `Single Play` and `Parallel Play`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of discussion, here is the result to solve this problem:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="btnSinglePlay" Visibility="Collapsed" my:VisibilityAnimation.IsActive="True">SinglePlay</Button>
        <Button Name="btnPlay" Click="btnPlay_Click">Play</Button>
        <Button Name="btnParallelPlay" Visibility="Collapsed" my:VisibilityAnimation.IsActive="True">ParallelPlay</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C# to set the 2 sides button visible.

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnSinglePlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            btnParallelPlay.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

And the c# code to permit the fade in/fade out. It comes from [WPF Fade Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013817/wpf-fade-animation) so props to Anvaka, not to me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class VisibilityAnimation : DependencyObject
    {
        private const int DURATION_MS = 200;

        private static readonly Hashtable _hookedElements = new Hashtable();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsActive",
          typeof(bool),
          typeof(VisibilityAnimation),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsActivePropertyChanged)));

        public static bool GetIsActive(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }

            return (bool)element.GetValue(IsActiveProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsActive(UIElement element, bool value)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            }
            element.SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
        }

        static VisibilityAnimation()
        {
            UIElement.VisibilityProperty.AddOwner(typeof(FrameworkElement),
                                                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, new PropertyChangedCallback(VisibilityChanged), CoerceVisibility));
        }

        private static void VisibilityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // So what? Ignore.
        }

        private static void OnIsActivePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (GetIsActive(fe))
            {
                HookVisibilityChanges(fe);
            }
            else
            {
                UnHookVisibilityChanges(fe);
            }
        }

        private static void UnHookVisibilityChanges(FrameworkElement fe)
        {
            if (_hookedElements.Contains(fe))
            {
                _hookedElements.Remove(fe);
            }
        }

        private static void HookVisibilityChanges(FrameworkElement fe)
        {
            _hookedElements.Add(fe, false);
        }

        private static object CoerceVisibility(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
        {
            var fe = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe == null)
            {
                return baseValue;
            }

            if (CheckAndUpdateAnimationStartedFlag(fe))
            {
                return baseValue;
            }
            // If we get here, it means we have to start fade in or fade out
            // animation. In any case return value of this method will be
            // Visibility.Visible. 

            var visibility = (Visibility)baseValue;

            var da = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DURATION_MS))
            };

            da.Completed += (o, e) =>
            {
                // This will trigger value coercion again
                // but CheckAndUpdateAnimationStartedFlag() function will reture true
                // this time, and animation will not be triggered.
                fe.Visibility = visibility;
                // NB: Small problem here. This may and probably will brake 
                // binding to visibility property.
            };

            if (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed || visibility == Visibility.Hidden)
            {
                da.From = 1.0;
                da.To = 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                da.From = 0.0;
                da.To = 1.0;
            }

            fe.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, da);
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private static bool CheckAndUpdateAnimationStartedFlag(FrameworkElement fe)
        {
            var hookedElement = _hookedElements.Contains(fe);
            if (!hookedElement)
            {
                return true; // don't need to animate unhooked elements.
            }

            var animationStarted = (bool)_hookedElements[fe];
            _hookedElements[fe] = !animationStarted;

            return animationStarted;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to create your 3 buttons and then put a visibility converter on your 2 sides buttons. Create a property that will hold if they should be visible or not and bind the visibility converter to this property. The `Play` button should modify this property when clicked.

I hope this gives you an idea on how to start with this.

Comment: And regard the visibility: can i do that in fade in / fade out ?

Comment: Yes you can, it has been answered here if you need more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013817/wpf-fade-animation

Comment: I added the VisibilityAnimation class and the style into Window.Resources but this line: loc:VisibilityAnimation.IsActive="True" i received error that the namespace prefix "loc" is not defined

Comment: loc is the namespace he is using for his code-behind. If you read his solution, he manually creates all the logic in code-behind. You could name it as you want.

Comment: i am sorry but i didn't understand what to do

Comment: Let's do this step by step, take away the fade. Create your 3 buttons and then bind them to a visibility converter. After that, try to modify the property when you click on the button to have the 2 other buttons appear/disappear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80195/discussion-between-maxime-tremblay-savard-and-verint-verint).